# How can I identify and make a table of repeated/identical variable1 values that have different variable2 values?

Tags: r

Example piece of the dataset: In this case, I would want to identify ID# 02002075 because there is a DOB for each of the two entries with this ID

```
id          dob    
00000745  19150406   
00000745  19150406
00102316  19231110    
00102316  19231110   
02002075  19450506  
02002075  19350107
```

I have a large data set and am currently focused on two columns. One is ID number and the other is DOB. There are some repeated ID numbers for multiple entries. However, some of the entries have the same ID numbers but different DOB. I need to identify these cases.

This gives me a data table of all the duplicated ID numbers, but I need help in figuring out how to then identify all the entries with a different DOB

```
d <- read_delim('data_headers_MS.txt', delim='\t'); dim(d)
x <- d[duplicated(d$id), ]; dim(x)
head(x)

ss <- x$id[x$id!='999999999']; length(ss)


ss <- unique(ss); length(ss) 

y <- subset(d, d$id %in% ss, select=c(id, soc.sec, dob, name.last, name.first, dx.age)); dim(y)

head(y)

y <- y[order(y$id), ]
```

Comment: Hi Melyssa. I popped your code into blocks using the code highlighting icon just above the box where you post you question. You are more likely to get an answer if you also edit to add a short example of your data. Perhaps by typing `head(d)` and `head(ss)`

Comment: I just added example data of these columns! Thank you

Comment: Thx Melyssa. For future reference the code icon is `{}` . Just highlight the code block and hit the icon and it will highlight code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(distinct_dob = length(unique(dob))) %>% 
  filter(distinct_dob > 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: What if I then wanted to sort by identical DOB values instead of distinct? I am having a hard time finding the command for that.

Comment: d %>% 
  group_by(id,dob) %>% 
  summarize(equal_dob = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id,equal_dob)